# I want to use zipline and backtest but data i am retrieving in saying not defined

Tags: python, zipline

```
from zipline import run_algorithm
from zipline.api import order_target_percent,symbol
from datetime import datetime
import pytz
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
def initalize(context):
    context.stock=symbol('AAPL')
    context.index_average_window=100
def handle_data(context,data):
    equities_data = data.history(context.stock, "close",context.index_average_window, "1d")
print(equities_data)


---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
----> 1 equities_data

NameError: name 'equities_data' is not defined

Comment: equities_data is outside the scope of function handle_data.